# How to add constraint where two of the column values should never contain same values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stuck on how to add unique constraints based on two columns. For ex:

```
Name    DOB         subject
Tony    18/09/1980  maths
sony    18/09/1980  english
Tony    19/01/1990  maths
Tony    18/09/1980  science
halo    17/6/1970   science
```

I can have multiple same names in the column `Name` but the `DOB` should not be the same for the same name. Row 1 and Row 4 are same with same `Names` and same `DOB`, where my database should restrict such entries with an alert. How do I do it ?

Query tried :

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.lecturer
  ADD CONSTRAINT unique_symbol_data UNIQUE(Name, DOB);
```

I wanted to add the other rows except the 6th row into my database

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here;  please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302)

Comment: I can assure you, someone's name and DOB is not enough to denote a unique person. When I was a child there was another child who had the same name (firstname and surname), DOB *and* they lived in the same street as me (so we had the same post code). I do not jest when I say my dentist *literally* identified us by our teeth *every* visit until one of us moved.

Comment: @ThomA, Thanks Thom, but my problem is to solve the above. The mentioned one is an example of my problem

Comment: You've tagged [[tag:rdbms]], *not* the RDBMS you are using... That's not helpful information.

Comment: well, what's the issue you're having when you add the above constraint?

Comment: @siggemannen its considering two values independently unique. I want it to be a combo as mentioned

Comment: no, it doesn't, it will consider the combo only

Comment: you can try it out yourself: https://dbfiddle.uk/GaYB6SwH . note that if you already have duplicates in the table, you won't be able to create the constraint until they are removed

Comment: Perhaps the real problem is that what my earlier comments tells you; that the columns you've chosen to be your unique columns aren't infact unique when combined.